# Div above content?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a newsletter so I have to make 2 columns and I used 2 divs at 50% of `width` to do it.
But the problem is that the div on the right goes above the content.

How could I fix that please? Thank's

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1ktxL36/7/#&togetherjs=dMjuryFAOl)

```css
#yellow {
  background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
#yellowL {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#yellowR {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
#h1v2 {
  color: rgb(67, 153, 186);
  background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow">
  <h1 id="h1v2">Geschäftsverlauf / Déroulement des affaires</h1>
  <div id="yellowL">
    <h1 id="h1v2">Offerten</h1>
    <p>

    </p>
    <h1 id="h1v2">Projekte</h1>
    <p>

    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="yellowR">
    <h1 id="h1v2">Offres</h1>
    <h2>Bruit</h2>
    <p>

    </p>
    <h2>Sols</h2>
    <p>

    </p>
    <h2>Déchets</h2>
    <p>

    </p>
    <h2>EIE</h2>
    <p>

    </p>
    <h2>Physique et acoustique du bâtiment</h2>
    <p>

    </p>
    <h1 id="h1v2">Projets</h1>
    <h2>Bruit</h2>
    <p>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v1ktxL36/7/#&togetherjs=dMjuryFAOl

Comment: Edit the question and include a [MCVE]. Don't just link to a third party hosted bit of code in a comment.

Comment: Emphasis on the word **Minimal**

Comment: I linked because, generally, people ask for a JsFiddle first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#yellow` css rule

```
#yellow {
    background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank's guy, it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to the div coming after these two:

```
#personnel {
    clear: both; 
}
```

I've edited your code in fiddle.
This will make all the content above to finish first before this new div starts.